# NDK can't find the application directory

Tags: android-ndk, makefile

When running the ndk-build command I get the following error:

```
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !    
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
```

The contents of my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := FRE
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := FlashRuntimeExtensions.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := NativeQCAR
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := FRE
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Adding the following line doesn't help:

```
NDK_PROJECT_PATH = C:/Users/Wessel/Dropbox/workspace/eclipse/NativeQ
```

Comment: Had the same issue just had to add `export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=[PATH TO MY NDK FOLDER]` to my `.bash_profile`. After that I could run the command from my project folder.

Comment: For using ndk-build to build your source code then your source code must be under jni folder because ndk-build as default set $LOCAL_PATH/jni is NDK_PROJECT_PATH. If you want to change NDK_PROJECT_PATH, ease to use ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH= $(pwd)  as example.

Answer (score 29):

You can use the following command

```
ndk-build -C your_project_path
```

Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: @SergBurlaka folder has 'Application.mk'.

Comment: You should path of ndk-build , I think folder is not important.

Comment: I like this method. It works for me. At least it reduce one step to create the NDK_PROJECT_PATH environmental variable.

Answer (score 27):

`NDK_PROJECT_PATH` is an environment variable so you don't have to include in the `Android.mk` file. Is `nkd-build` launched in the project directory?

For more info read the docs in `docs/HOWTO.html` in the NDK folder where I read

> Starting with NDK r4, you can simply place the file under $PROJECT/jni/
>   and launch the 'ndk-build' script from your project tree.
>
> If you want to use 'ndk-build' but place the file to a different location,
>   use a GNU Make variable override as:
>
> ```
> ndk-build NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/path/to/your/Application.mk
> ```

Comment: The problem was that I only had C source files and no Android Java project. The solution was to put all the files in a folder called 'jni' and then run the ndk-build command. It finally worked!

But thanks for your fast answer :)

Comment: Yes, it is vital that one point to the directory that has Application.mk when running **ndk-build** command.

Answer (score 20):

I haven't found a single answer which is satisfactory for me, perhaps it depends whether you're trying to build an existing application, create a new one, or perhaps you are porting some existing native app. These guidelines work with android-ndk-r9b but should work with the last few releases

The makefile build-local.mk used by ndk-build will make some guesses about the location of the application makefile.

By default it seems the NDK is oriented towards having you stow your NDK application `Application.mk` and `Android.mk` files under a sub-directory called `jni`. This works nicely, and you can just use the command line:

```
$ ndk-build
```

If you don't want to have a `jni` sub-directory, for example, perhaps you're porting a linux command-line tool to Android, the following maybe appropriate for you:

Create an empty `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Now create an `Application.mk` file with the following contents:

```
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := Android.mk
```

Then create an `Android.mk` file, for example:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo.c
LOCAL_MODULE := foo
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

To build the application use:

```
$ ndk-build NDK_APPLICATION_MK=`pwd`/Application.mk
```

Comment: Instead of creating all of those files, I went with `ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=$(pwd) APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=$(pwd)/Android.mk` on the command line.  Your answer helped me figure that out.

Comment: I was missing a "jni" folder.  And this was a nice work around.

Comment: BTW, GrandAdmiral's short-cut worked...until I learned that the only way to define APP_STL is in Application.mk.  For some reason, APP_STL cannot be defined in Android.mk.  So tonylo's solution is what I ended up using.

Comment: This is the best answer, as it got down to the root problem: having your **Android.mk** in the jni directory.

Comment: where i need call this command ??? $ ndk-build NDK_APPLICATION_MK=`pwd`/Application.mk

Answer (score 18):

You need to specify 3 things.

```
NDK_PROJECT_PATH - the location of your project
NDK_APPLICATION_MK - the path of the Application.mk file
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT - the path to the Android.mk file
```

These are needed to  override the default values of the build script, which expects things to be in the jni folder.

When calling ndk-build use

```
ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/path/to/proj NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/path/to/Application.mk
```

In Application.mk add

```
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := /path/to/Android.mk
```

Answer (score 18):

```
ndk-build NDK_APPLICATION_MK=path\to\your\src\main\jni\Application.mk NDK_PROJECT_PATH=path\to\your\module\src\main
```

Comment: where i need write this?

Answer (score 14):

This is what I use, `cd` into the project directory and do:

```
ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=.
```

[image]

Comment: Do this, plus put your files in a sub folder called jni.

Answer (score 4):

Follow Below steps:

```
1)Right on your project
2)Go to properties
3)Go to C/C++ Build
4)Go to Builder Settings
5)Go to Build Location
  Add build directory
6)Click on Workspace
7)Select your project folder
```

you should see something like

```
${workspace_loc:/[Your Project_Name]}
```

Done!!

Answer (score 4):

`-C` worked for me.

[image]

You can also use the mac terminal to do this.

Comment: Hi unfortunetly my ndk-bundle doesn't contain any folder named ndk build any  suggestion about the same ?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. No environment variables and no setups. Go to the root directory where you unzipped ndk on command line and run ndk-build command:

> ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=path to your project

A sample would look like this in my dev machine:

```
 C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\android-ndk-r9d>ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=D: /workspace/naruto  
 Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersi on 9 in D:/workspace/naruto/AndroidManifest.xml
 [armeabi] Compile thumb  : ndkfoo <= ndkfoo.c 
 [armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libndkfoo.so 
 [armeabi] Install        : libndkfoo.so => libs/armeabi/libndkfoo.so
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow steps below:

1.Go to folder containing Android.mk

2.Assign the android-ndk path to $NDK_PROJECT_PATH. eg: export NDK_PROJECT_PATH =/home/android-ndk-r8b.

3.Add NDK to $PATH. eg: export PATH=$PATH:/home/android-ndk-r8b.

Answer (score 1):

Set your ndk builder's working directory could solve your problem as I got the same problem and solved it in this way.

Path: Project Properties -> Builders ->  -> Main -> Working Directory