# Compiling React Native project with local fork - NDK_PROJECT_PATH

Tags: android, android-ndk, react-native

I'm trying to compile my React Native Android project using a local fork of react-native. I've followed the [building from source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html) guide and completed all steps (not using Android Studio).

When I try to run `react-native run-android` (from project root as normal), I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ReactAndroid:buildReactNdkLib'.
> Process 'command '/usr/local/opt/android-ndk/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

When I run `ndk-build` (from project root), I get:

```
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
/usr/local/Cellar/android-ndk/r12b/build/core/build-local.mk:151: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

[Another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156596/ndk-cant-find-the-application-directory) pointed me in the direction of running `ndk-build` from `./android/app/src` and create a `jni` directory there (I didn't have one), but I'm unsure how to obtain or create `jni/Android.mk` correctly or if this will even help me. I've tried creating `jni/Application.mk` with contents `APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := Android.mk` and `jni/Android.mk` with the setup described in that SO question. Running `ndk-build` from `android/app/src` exits with the following error:

```
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: Android.mk
/usr/local/Cellar/android-ndk/r12b/build/core/add-application.mk:198: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

I have the Android SDK and NDK installed with Homebrew and I have the following exports:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
ANDROID_SDK=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
ANDROID_NDK=/usr/local/opt/android-ndk
ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-ndk
```

I feel like I'm close, but have no idea how to continue.

Comment: No, you cannot run ndk-build from command line for react-native. Its gradle scripts download and configure a lot of dependencies, including boost. You can run `react-native --debug run-android` to find more about the failure of  ':ReactAndroid:buildReactNdkLib'. I recommend to open an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20buildReactNdkLib).

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with `android-ndk` version. We need to use ndk version specified by react-native [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html#download-links-for-android-ndk). I tried with the latest version of andrid-ndk. I was not able to build the project, got similar error while running `react-native run-android`.

Then I tried with [android-ndk-r10e](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r10e-darwin-x86_64.zip) version. It worked fine, I was able to build the project successfully.

Also you may find [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6689) react-native github issue discussion useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to compile React Native UIExplorer for Android.And I have same issue.
Then I run `ndk-build` ,I get:

```
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
/usr/local/Cellar/android-ndk/r13b/build/core/build-local.mk:151: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

My `android-ndk` version is `/android-ndk/r13b/`,So I download [android-ndk-r10e](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r10e-darwin-x86_64.zip) .
I use the most direct way：

```
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/android-ndk/r13b 
$ rm -rf ./*
$ mv YourUnZipPath/android-ndk-r10e/* ./
```

Then It worked fine, I was able to build the project successfully.