# How to set NDK_PROJECT_PATH in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am very new to NDK debugging and I am trying to build the cpp code for debugging.

This is how my Application.mk file looks :

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_MODULES := abc xyz
APP_CFLAGS += -fno-rtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
NDK_TOOLCHAIN := arm-linux-androideabi-4.9
```

and I an getting the following error , I have tried all the toolchains in ndk tools , what am I missing ?

[image]

update:
 I realized that NDK_PROJECT_PATH is set to null , when built is run from Android studio. I am able to run

ndk-build -C  from the terminal.

Actually my ultimate aim is to be able to debug native c++ files , by setting break points.

So current scenario:
I have native code in xyz folder with has jni folder containing android.mk and application.mk

I can run ndk-build in this folder and get the .so files, which I manually copy paste in jnilibs folder of the my android app (say appB):

This is the gradle of the appB :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 13
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

Later I use this app as dependency in another app say appA.

This is the gradle of appA:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*****"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:24.1.0'
    compile project(':appB')
}
```

I need to be able to debug, 
appA (which I can)
appB (which I can)
native code included as .so in appB (which I dont know yet how to)
aap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29471014/5628333

Answer (score 4):

You can update the Android Studio to 2.2.2, and use the menu File-> Link C ++ Project with Gradle.
The official ndk samples can be found [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk)!

Comment: I have been trying to do that since 2 days now, I have multiple APP_MODULES in application.mk but I do not get .so for all modules in my app-debug.apk

Answer (score 0):

There will be a local.properties files in your project folder from where the sdk & ndk paths can be configured. Normally the file has sdk directory path, you can configure your ndk path using keywork ndk.dir. For example

```
sdk.dir=YOUR_PATH_TO_SDK  ( sdk.dir= /home/Android/Sdk)
ndk.dir=YOUR_PATH_TO_SDK ( ndk.dir= /home/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle)
```

Comment: He was asking about NDK_PROJECT_PATH  not NDK_DIR