# How to find the path to NDK?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I installed `NDK` using Android Studio (SDK Manager). Where is the default directory of `NDK` for Mac? How do I find the path to it?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156596/ndk-cant-find-the-application-directory

Comment: @sasikumar So NDK_PROJECT_PATH and Path to NDK is the same thing?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

My understanding is that now the NDK bundle is being offered via the SDK Manager within Android Studio, it will install into the Android SDK directory as per the other components (platforms, build tools, support repositories, etc.) in the SDK Manager.

You can check the location of the SDK directory itself via Android Studio -> Preferences... -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> Android SDK Location field near the top of the panel.

I've customised mine (it's editable) so I'm afraid I don't know what the default is, but if you check the contents of the directory listed in that field then the NDK should be installed into a subdirectory called `ndk-bundle`.

Comment: it seems that default one is /Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle

Comment: CMD-Shift-. (dot) to show hidden folders in the Finder (~/Library is hidden)

Comment: If after following the instructions above, the `ndk-bundle` isn't in the SDK folder, you can download it by clicking on the "SDK Tools" tab in the "Android SDK" preferences pane, selecting "NDK" in the list of tools, and clicking "Apply" to download it.

Comment: After installing the NDK from `Setting > System Setting > Android SDK > SDK Tools` I am only getting a folder named `ndk` inside of /Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk.
There is no folder called `ndk-bundle` 
is  `/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/ndk` the NDK path ??

Answer (score 11):

You can find it on `$ANDROID_SDK_PATH/ndk-bundle`.
`ANDROID_SDK_PATH` is your SDK path which I suppose you have set it already.

Comment: Instead of `ndk-bundle` now it is just `ndk` -->
`/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/ndk`

Answer (score 3):

Finding your SDK/NDK library path needs information about how you installed them. However, there are two possible solutions to find them

1. Using Android Studio: the possible way to find is using Android Studio. Open your Android Studio Preference (or "File->Settings") > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK. You can find the path to your SDK and NDK, which is in the same directory.
2. Using Terminal: Open Terminal and put the command as below. Hopefully, if ANDROID_HOME environment has been set.

   echo $ANDROID_HOME